# How much charge is on this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, charge, homework

The capacitor C is fully charged by the battery while the switch is in position A.  The switch is then thrown to position B. Compute the charge on the capacitors and the resulting voltages.  The battery is 100 volts.

[image]

I tried to compute $$15 \space \mu F*100\space V=0.0015 \space C$$ to find out how much charge was *available* for the resulting situation. But reverse engineering the answer, even this is wrong.  It it trivial to find the voltage on each capacitor (it has to add up to 100, right?) if we know the charge, but clearly I am failing to do that.

Initially, I assumed the charge would be divided evenly.  But then I realized that since not all capacitors have the same internal field, this is probably not the case - each wire will have a (potentially) unique potential difference across of it!

I must admit, this problem has me stumped.  If anyone could explain just the *method* for how to approach this, I can check the answer myself.

Thanks!

Comment: You're off by an order of magnitude 1.5mC, not 15.

Answer (score 3):

> it has to add up to 100, right?

Wrong.

The problem is incompletely specified, the intital charge on C2 and C3 is not specified. Lets assume it's zero.

Before the swtich is flicked C1 is fully charged. After the switch is flicked, some of that charge moves to C2 and C3.

Since you have the same ammount of charge and a greater total capacitance that means the voltage is reduced and energy is lost.

If the switch is repeatedly moved back and forth more charge is transffered each time and the voltage on C2 and C3 will rise towards the battery voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bottom node as the reference (-).
$$ V_{C1} = V_{C2} + V_{C3} $$
So the voltages of the capacitor do not add up to the input voltage. This is just KVL.

Apply the flow of charge has to be the same around the loop (equivalent of KCL). Let \$ \Delta Q \$ be the charge that goes around the loop of C1, C2 and C3.

$$ Q_1 = C_1 V - \Delta Q $$
$$ Q_2 = 0 + \Delta Q $$
$$ Q_3 = 0 + \Delta Q $$

Add on
$$ Q_1 = C_1 V_{C1},\  Q_2 = C_2 V_{C2},\  Q_3 = C_3 V_{C3} $$

Solve the 7 equations with 7 unknowns.